# How to split sub details sections individually?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, crystal-reports

in my crystal report i have Detail a and Detail b.now i want to split Detail a into two columns and Detail b into three columns.any suggestions? Thank you

ex:

```
Detail a

Column 1       Column 2 
value          value
value          value

Detail b

Column 1      Column 2     Column 3
value         value        value 
value         value        value
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achive this using Sub Report option.

1. One sub report with 2 columns in that in Detail a
2. Another sub report with 3 columns in Detail b.

Comment: i have tried it.but in the main report all the data shows in one column.is it possible to divide sub detail sections individually ?

Comment: To the extent I understand.. don't keep any columns in main report in main report there should only be 2 subreports and becareful while making the linkings to the sub report from main report.